# Timestamp format changes when writing file in csv format in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing my data to my local using spark write

below is the code

```
spark_raw_5.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").option("header","true")
.option("escape", "\"").option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").
csv("/Users/adityaverma/Downloads/accounts_spark_output.csv")
```

Now when I do a show **spark_raw_5.show()** it shows me the correct timestamp which is

```
2017-03-17 05:41:36
```

but when I am writing this data into my local and opeining it into excel it shows me a complete different timestamp which is not accepted.

OUTPUT:

```
17/03/2017  5:41:36 AM
```

Please help me so that my output looks like **'2017-03-17 05:41:36'**

Comment: That's not a problem with Spark but just Excel trying to be smart. Use the data import wizard and tell Excel to treat the column as text, not as timestamp.

Comment: Worked for me but had to struggle little not straight forward. Somehow used this but didn't work straight forward